# Реализовать алгоритм рекурсивно и итерационно

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Стоит задача решить рекурсией и итерационно
[image: 11]

`a` и `b` вводят с клавиатуры.
Попытался сделать рекурсией сам, однако так и не понял, где она должна возникать. Может у вас есть какие-то идеи, что я делаю не так?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int recursion(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    if (b > 0)
        return (a + 1) + (b - 1);
    else if (b < 0)
        return (a - 1) + (b + 1);
}

int main() {
    int a;
    cout << "Enter: a= \n";
    cin >> a;
    int b;
    cout << "Enter: b= \n";
    cin >> b;
    cout << " " << recursion(a, b) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а с какого бока тут рекурсию прикручивать то?

Comment: да я сам не шарю. препод сказал сделай мне рекурсию и цыкл. сказал : "а чем ето тебе не напоминает f(a,b)".  и я такой :\

Comment: я думаю, что нужно для начала повторить правила русского языка... "ц**и**кл"

Comment: @KoVadim Не чтят великих... [*"- Помимо математических способностей, жизненно важным качеством программиста является исключительно хорошее владение родным языком." Дейкстра*](https://bit.ly/3q1BVJS)

Comment: ну для меня русский никогда не был родным, я знаю его очень очень плохо, до 10 лет я даже не понимал его (потом пришлось учить), но проверка синтаксиса в хроме делает чудеса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int recursion (int a, int b)
{
    if ( b == 0 ) return a;
    if (b > 0)
        return recursion(a + 1,b - 1);
    else
        return recursion(a - 1,b + 1);
}
```

Итеративно:

```
int iteration (int a, int b)
{
    while(b > 0) {a++; b--; }
    while(b < 0) {a--; b++; }
    return a;
}
```